# jquery javascript problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, get, split

Could you please take a look and tell why this isnt working i cant figure it out. the problem is with

```
$("#item_name").val(item_name);
$("#amount").val(course_price);
```

This should be adding info to 2 hidden inputs (

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name"value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
```

)
but they are coming up as blank

also the value from course_name.php?courseID=1 is Course Name,500

**Full Javascript**

```
<script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
url = "date_range.php?courseID="+$('#course_name').val();
  $("#dates").load(url)
  url = "course_name.php?courseID="+$('#course_name').val();
   var course_details;
$.get(url, function(data){
    course_details= data;
});
   split_course_details = course_details.split(',');
   course_name=split_course_details[0];
   course_price=split_course_details[1];
   course_date=$("#date_range").val();
   item_name=course_name+' - '+course_date;
   $("#item_name").val(item_name);
    $("#amount").val(course_price);


      });


$('#course_name').change(function() {
    url = "date_range.php?courseID="+$('#course_name').val();
  $("#dates").load(url)
  url = "course_name.php?courseID="+$('#course_name').val();
  var course_details;
$.get(url, function(data){
    course_details= data;
});
   split_course_details = course_details.split(',');
   course_name=split_course_details[0];
   course_price=split_course_details[1];
   course_date=$("#date_range").val();
   item_name=course_name+' - '+course_date;
   $("#item_name").val(item_name);
    $("#amount").val(course_price);
});

</script>
```

Comment: 2 hidden inputs with the same ID? IDs are supposed to be unique, no surprise it fails.

Comment: with the relevant ID's i wrote it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your calculation inside the callback function of `$.get()`, like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    url = "date_range.php?courseID=" + $('#course_name').val();
    $("#dates").load(url)
    url = "course_name.php?courseID=" + $('#course_name').val();
    var course_details;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        course_details = data;
        split_course_details = course_details.split(',');
        course_name = split_course_details[0];
        course_price = split_course_details[1];
        course_date = $("#date_range").val();
        item_name = course_name + ' - ' + course_date;
        $("#item_name").val(item_name);
        $("#amount").val(course_price);
    });

});

$('#course_name').change(function() {
    url = "date_range.php?courseID=" + $('#course_name').val();
    $("#dates").load(url)
    url = "course_name.php?courseID=" + $('#course_name').val();
    var course_details;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        course_details = data;
        split_course_details = course_details.split(',');
        course_name = split_course_details[0];
        course_price = split_course_details[1];
        course_date = $("#date_range").val();
        item_name = course_name + ' - ' + course_date;
        $("#item_name").val(item_name);
        $("#amount").val(course_price);
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly. $.get is asynchronous by default, so any data that is returned needs to be handled in the success callback.

Comment: actually this did fix the issue. I wasnt testing it correctly.

Comment: @limc Notice that you have the same code twice - once in the ready callback and once in the change callback. This should be optimized to remove the redundancy. You can do it by simply triggering the change event on page load (right after you assign the change callback), like so: `elem.change( callbackfunction ).change();`.

Comment: @limc Also, the variables are not declared, so they become implicit global variables. You have to declare them using `var` to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    var cname = $('#course_name'),
        dates = $('#dates'),
        iname = $('#item_name'),
        amount = $('#amount'),
        drange = $('#date_range');

    cname.change(function() {    
        dates.load( 'date_range.php?courseID=' + this.value );

        $.get('course_name.php?courseID=' + this.value, function(data) {
            data = data.split(',');    
            iname.val( data[0] + ' - ' + drange.val() );
            amount.val( data[1] );
        });
    }).change();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're using url variable twice for different data...
try using additional variable..